# What is the best approach to implementing a password-protected first screen using a storyboard?

Tags: swift, xcode

In Xcode, when using a storyboard, I want to have the first screen that appears which would have a lock screen for the rest of the app.

All I want is a button and a TextField on this first screen. I would like the user only to see the rest of the app's contents if they can input the correct password on the first screen.

What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Well, my knowledge is quite limited, but the only thing I could think of was to have a button that would execute navigation from the main view controller to a separate one but I can't seem to find out how I would incorporate the text field in order to check if the navigation should happen or not.

Comment: most of my research suggests creating a login feature with the app and keeping all of the accounts saved but this seemed a little unnecessary as I am only going to have this app on one singular phone.

Comment: my point is that there's tons of tutorials that provide different ways of implementing some sort of login - from simplest ones (e.g. https://guides.codepath.com/ios/Creating-a-Log-In-Screen) - to "local login" using something like Keychain to store credentials - to sophisticated ones. Best is if you take one of these tutorials, implement it and then ask concrete questions if something doesn't match your expectations